Romans 11, 16-24: wild branches on fruit root?
In Romans 11, 16-24, Paul depicts the image of a grafted olive tree.

16 If the part of the dough offered as firstfruits is holy, then the whole batch is holy; if the root is holy, so are the branches.
17 If some of the branches have been broken off, and you, though a wild olive shoot, have been grafted in among the others and now share in the nourishing sap from the olive root, 18 do not consider yourself to be superior to those other branches. If you do, consider this: You do not support the root, but the root supports you. 19 You will say then, “Branches were broken off so that I could be grafted in.” 20 Granted. But they were broken off because of unbelief, and you stand by faith. Do not be arrogant, but tremble. 21 For if God did not spare the natural branches, he will not spare you either.
22 Consider therefore the kindness and sternness of God: sternness to those who fell, but kindness to you, provided that you continue in his kindness. Otherwise, you also will be cut off. 23 And if they do not persist in unbelief, they will be grafted in, for God is able to graft them in again. 24 After all, if you were cut out of an olive tree that is wild by nature, and contrary to nature were grafted into a cultivated olive tree, how much more readily will these, the natural branches, be grafted into their own olive tree!

I find this piece very difficult, not only for its metaphorical meaning, but also for the image that is used.
Up to my knowledge, fruity branches are used as scions and grafted in a wild root (and not vice-versa!).
Is there some implicit argument the reader should take into account in this picture (why are wild branches grafted in domestic root?)? Or the reader should just avoid to question about the real grafting practice, as it's just not the point (no matter what gets grafted in what, in reality: the reader should be able to keep the point and go ahead with the metaphor)?

It is a metaphor - do not be distracted with practical details!

@Dottard yes, I think this is the correct answer to my question.

The point being made is the wildness of the Gentiles being graciously grated in to a cultivated olive tree. That is the whole point of the metaphor.

The idea of Paul inverting a metaphor is not unusual for him.  He does that in 2 Corinthians where he brags about his weakness.  He does that there to emphasize and draw focused attention on a reality:  "When I am weak, then I am strong," it makes Christ's power obvious.  In the same way, the odd nature expressed by the inverting of the horticultural process highlights the gracious and undeserving nature of wild Gentiles being grafted into a cultivated Jewish tree.  The metaphor is backwards because the reality is backwards.  And, I, a Gentile, am very thankful for that.

Here’s the key: Paul is using this image to make a theological point, not a horticultural one.
The “wild branches” represent Gentile believers, while the “cultivated root” represents the Jewish people and their covenant relationship with God. Paul’s point is that through faith in Christ, Gentiles have been grafted into the promises and blessings originally given to the Jews.
Bibleref puts it this way:

Paul seems to be eager for Gentile Christians to reach two goals.
First, to understand that this re-grafting is possible. Second, to
look forward to it themselves. After all, God could cut them from the
wild olive tree—the unspiritual religions of the world—and graft them
into His own cultivated tree through faith in Christ. Therefore, God
can graft back into His tree the branches that grew there in the first
place.
Grafting wild olive tree branches into cultivated trees is not the
natural way to raise olive trees. Symbolically speaking, it was not
"natural" for God to do this in order to offer salvation to the
Gentiles, though it is exactly what He has done. Paul's point is to
highlight the way a Gentile Christian ought to look at the potential
salvation of the Jewish people. What could be more natural than for
God to welcome the Jewish people back into His family, as they begin
to trust in Christ for their salvation?

Paul, not being a horticulturists, the metaphor might not align with typical grafting practices. It’s the theological message that’s important here. Paul is using a familiar process, grafting, to illustrate a profound spiritual truth: the inclusion of the Gentiles in God’s covenant community.

"The greatest benefit of olive tree grafting is cross-pollination."
-- from https://www.oliviadaolive.com/grafting-olive-trees-techniques-aftercare/
This non-biblical quote nonetheless is interesting - are God's people more prolific when we interact with believers from a different background?  In this passage it would refer to connecting Jews with non-Jews.

Are you saying that the meaning is that syncretism (the opposite of Jeremiah 10:2's "Thus saith the LORD, Learn not the way of the heathen …")  is a good thing?
